# How can I break up a Flask Blueprint into multiple files within a subfolder?

Tags: python, flask

### Background

I have a Flask app with a folder structure roughly as follows:

```
/server
    /templates/
    /__init__.py
    /api.py
    /app.py
```

- `api.py` contains Flask routes that are registed with a Flask Blueprint named "api".
- `app.py` is the file I run when I want to start the Flask app.

---

### Goal

I want to break up the api.py file into multiple files, so that the structure will look as follows:

```
/server
    /api/
        /__init__.py
        /account.py
        /song.py
    /app.py
    /templates/
```

---

### Problem

However, when I do this, I get a "View function did not return a response" error when any of the routes inside those new files are accessed:

```
[2019-01-30 07:58:32,940] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/app/load/ [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\rhymecraft\server\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\rhymecraft\server\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\rhymecraft\server\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\rhymecraft\server\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1725, in make_response
    raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')
ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

---

### Question

How can I break up a Flask Blueprint into multiple files within a subfolder?

Comment: Where are you registering your blueprints? What is the view function that raises the error? I'm not sure there's anywhere near enough info to answer this as-is

Comment: @roganjosh re #1 - The Blueprint object is created within `/api/__init__.py` and is registered within `app.py`.  re: #2 - It's a view function within `/api/song.py` that loads a song to the front end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

The problem was that the new `api/__init__.py` file was not importing the routes from the new non-`__init__.py` files (`/api/account.py` and `/api/song.py`).

So when the Blueprint was registed within `app.py`, it was just doing `from api import api`, but there was never any code which would have caused the code within the `account.py` and `song.py` modules to get run.

The solution was to:

1. update `api/__init__.py` to include a `from api.account import *` and `from api.song import *` at the top.
2. move the Blueprint object's definition out of the `/api/__init__.py` and into a new `/api/utils.py` file so that it could be imported by all of the route-containing files (`/api/__init__.py`, `/api/account.py`, and `/api/song.py`).

   - This is just preventing a circular import error.